# Is l18n_diffsource just a misspelled field in TYPO3?

Tags: database, localization, internationalization, typo3

The abbreviations i18n for internationalization and l10n for localization are common.

In the world of TYPO3 in *tt_content* I find *l18n_parent*, *l18n_diffsource*. Note the small leading L! In *pages* there is a field *l18n_cfg*.

Is this just a typo that has never been fixed or is there any meaning behind?

Comment: I am not sure, maybe its a combination of both international + localization :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it is a typo that got not fixed as it would have needed fixes in the core and all extensions which had been written meanwhile and which use these fields.
Also it would need update wizards for all existing installations.